# Python - Nltk pos spanish

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm new to `nlp` and i have been reading a lot about `nltk`. I'm from South America and I want to start using nltk with Spanish texts. I read the docs but i only found how to stem Spanish words. Maybe I am wrong or maybe I just could not find that part of the documentation. I also read a few blogs about the subject.

The question is: Is there an "official" or most practical way to use pos tags in Spanish?

Comment: @SalvadorDali i have read the other SO questions, that's why i am asking a new one, because none of the rest helped

Comment: Then your question should explain this, and provide more details about which part you are having trouble with.

Comment: @nachomiguel No, there is no official way. `Spaghetti-tagger` is a tutorial on how to train your own using NLTK and a tagged corpora. Given a tagged corpus, you can do something like what i've did with indotag using CRFsuite or CRF++ (http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C/C14/C14-2019.pdf) or you can simply wrap tools like Freeling https://github.com/djinn/freeling-python

Comment: @alvas thanks i will start with that. Very helpful

Comment: Freeling is a very good option. In the past I also used TreeTagger http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/ which also has a Python wrapper https://github.com/miotto/treetagger-python/blob/master/treetagger.py

Comment: You can use Stanford NLP for the spanish pos Tags. Please refer to the below link. Hope this links helps you [https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/]
[https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/spanish-faq.shtml#tagset]